# Port forwarding to virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm running an http(zope) server on Ubuntu 8.04 server, in a Virtualbox machine, on an Ubuntu 9.04 box. The guest system accesses network over NAT. How can I forward the host machine's port 80 to the guest system's http port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable port forwarding in VirtualBox. You can do that by using the `VBoxManage` command. For example:

```
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guesthttp/HostPort" 8888
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guesthttp/GuestPort" 80
VBoxManage setextradata VM_NAME "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/guesthttp/Protocol" TCP
```

In this case, this will open port 8888/tcp on your host (physical machine), and forward it to port 80/tcp of your virtual machine (replace VM_NAME with the name of your virtual machine).

For more details, see "*Configuring port forwarding with NAT*" in the [VirtualBox User Manual](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.0.4/UserManual.pdf) (section 6.4.1, p. 84)

If you need external access to the web server hosted on your virtual machine, then you'd also need to create a port forwarding rule (for example through `iptables` or configuring it in your router).

Comment: For the detailed iptables rules, see this post: http://mydebian.blogdns.org/?p=111

Answer (score 0):

figure out what ip address has the guest system (though it's dhcp assigned, it's more likely it will have the same address after reboot; if not, switch to static ip's)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 0/0 -d IP_HOST -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to IP_GUEST:80
```